# How to change colour select button in kendo ui upload

Tags: kendo-ui

How to change the select button in kendo ui upload, i add background-color:#3399FF; but it does not work in IE 8. I have modified using the following CSS but not working in IE 8. Please advise.

```
<form method="post" action='@Url.Action("Index")' style="width:45%">
    <div>
        <table style="border:0">
        <tr style="border:0;">
             <span>Import Consumer List:</span>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border:"0">
            <td style="border:0;">
             @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { @Style = "align:center; font-size:12px" })     
                    .Name("FileUpload")
                    .Multiple(false)
                    .Events(ev => ev.Success("onSuccess"))
            )
            </td>
            <td style="border:0;">
                <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Import" style="height:31px; font-size:14px; background-color:#3399FF" class="k-button" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>


.k-upload-button {
    direction: ltr;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    position: relative;
    width: 86px;
    font-size:14px;
    background-color:#3399FF;   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have your `kendoUpload` defined as:

```
<form method="post" action="submit" style="width:45%">
    <div>
        <input name="files" id="files" type="file" />
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="k-button" />
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

and the following initialization:

```
$("#files").kendoUpload({});
```

you might define the style for `Submit` button as:

```
input.k-button {
    direction: ltr;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    position: relative;
    width: 86px;
    font-size:14px;
    background-color:#3399FF;
}
```

or:

```
#submit.k-button {
    direction: ltr;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    position: relative;
    width: 86px;
    font-size:14px;
    background:#3399FF;
}
```

Comment: Hi OnaBai, i am current looking for to change the button color of select button in the kendoui upload not the submit. Thx

Comment: Which version of KendoUI are you using? Try specifying `background` as in my example of `#submit.k-button` and not just `background-color`.

Comment: Kendo ui version 2012. still does not work. I have update my code

Comment: @Supermode - did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<style>
    .k-upload-button{
        background-color:crimson !important;
    }
</style>
```